# How to remove the bottom panel in install page in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

Please find the attached image where i am not able to remove the bottom bar. please help me in this regard. i want to put some text on the bottom bar area after removal. i want to remove the bar only in install page.

Comment: Thank you for your help. i got the solution that you have posted

Comment: Hi TLama, How to remove the bar only in install page except any other page .

Comment: Modify your question, I'll remove my duplicate mark and answer you...

Comment: Hello, i got the solution by puting the  if CurPageID = wpInstalling then
  begin
  WizardForm.Bevel.Visible := False; i have put it in curpagechange procedure. it worked
  WizardForm.Bevel1.Visible := False;
  end;

Comment: That's also correct. But easier to read is the `WizardForm.Bevel.Visible := CurPageID <> wpInstalling` way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideal place for tracking page changing is the [`CurPageChanged`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm#CurPageChanged) event method, in which you need to set the `Visible` property of the `Bevel` control depending on the page ID passed to the event method by the `CurPageID` parameter. To fit your requirement you'll need to show the bevel only if you are not on the installing page represented by the `wpInstalling` constant:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  WizardForm.Bevel.Visible := CurPageID <> wpInstalling;
end;
```